# LuaTeX readline encoding

Tags: luatex, input-encodings, write-file

**Must LuaTeX's `\readline` use latin-1 encoding?**

In the example below, I first store `é` in a file (well, and `^^J`) which works well.  Then I read it back in, using `\readline` and get two characters `Ã©` (and `^^M`).  Then writing it back to a file yields those two characters (or rather, the bytes in their utf-8 encoding).  I would like to be able to do the round-trip "reading a utf-8 file and writing it back" without modification (besides some end-line space trimming perhaps).

```
% Write some Unicode char to a file tmp.aux
\immediate\openout5=tmp.aux
\immediate\write5{é}
\immediate\closeout5
%
% Read it back in, _using \readline_
\openin6=tmp.aux
\readline6 to \foo
\closein6
%
\message{\foo}                   % => Ā© and a carriage return
%
% Write again: the file is different from tmp.aux.
\immediate\openout5=out.aux
\immediate\write5{\foo}
\immediate\closeout5
%
\csname bye\endcsname
\csname @@end\endcsname
```

Using `\read` instead of `\readline` avoids the encoding problem but tokenizes the lines, which I don't want to do.

Comment: For information.  This odd behaviour of `\readline` causes a bug in my `morewrites` package.

Comment: In my files are always é. Only out.aux with an additional CR. Linux with de_DE.utf8 and luatex beta-0.79.1

Comment: With TL2014 all looks good here: I get the odd `Ã©` with the TL2012 release of LuaTeX.

Comment: @josephWright so I guess the answer is "bug in LuaTeX, fixed in the newest available release" (well, not quite available yet)?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I guess so: TL2013 also gives a slightly odd result. I've not tested in MiKTeX, but it's likely to have the latest LuaTeX so is probably correct.

Comment: Back in the olden days I would vote to close this question as too localized, but the option seems to have disappeared.  In any case, please feel free to close it.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the comments, this issue seems to be solved by using the most recent version of LuaTeX, which seems to treat encodings in the same way for `\read` and `\readline`.